# django redirect error: NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

I'm working with Django 1.9, and I keep getting this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /class/create/
>
> Reverse for 'class_sheet' with
>   arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'class_name': 'd'}' not found.
>   0 pattern(s) tried: []

I have this in my app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...

def class_sheet(request, class_name):
  get_object_or_404(EnclaveClass, pk=class_name)
  return HttpResponse("this is %s" % class_name)

def create_class(request):
 return redirect('class_sheet', class_name='d')
```

in my urs.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  url(r'^create/$', views.create_class, name="create_class"),
  url(r'^(?P<class_name>.*)/$', views.class_sheet, name="class_sheet"),
  ...
]
```

I haven't been able to find any posts online that indicates anything in my function is wrong. Any advice on how to fix or where to look is appreciated.

Comment: Have you specified `namespace` when including URLs, e. g. `include('app.urls', namespace='app')`? If so, you should to use `app:class_sheet` to reverse it.

Comment: That worked! The name-spacing is where I deviated from the tutorial I was using. Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `'app:class_sheet'`, where `app` is `namespace` used in including URLs: `include('app.urls', namespace='app')`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not specify the name-space! Changing create_class to

```
def create_class(request):
    return redirect('class:class_sheet', class_name='d')
```

Got the redirect to work.

Many thanks to Vladimir Danilov in the comment for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the CONSOLE in your browser if the request to this URL is satisfying the Regular Expression in the URL?

Comment: When I take out the redirect and just go to /class/create, it is perfectly happy showing me content. (You can also see in the "create" URL pattern in the code snippet.)

Comment: My mistake, I just checked your class_sheet URL pattern's Regex and it is matching the "/class/create/" url and it should.
But what is the URL pattern you want to form actually? Can give any example?

Comment: P.S. You can check the Regular Expression for your URL yourself on any of the website for Regular Expression.
One of them is ->  http://pythex.org/

Comment: I want it to go to /class/d.

Comment: I'm trying to call the function 'class_sheet(request, class_name)' in views.py, it happens to be the same function that the second url in my code url.py snippet calls.

Comment: Just to provide you more info, you can either use "class:class_sheet" in your views and use class_sheet in your html template, or it works the other way round too, that you write "class:class_sheet" in your HTML template and write class_sheet in your views(without specifying the name-space)